# Merging verts by distance breaks smooth shading (Blender 2.8)

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves, normals

I created a wall piece from a cube, applied smooth shading to it and then used the array modifier, but after merging the verts by distance, it mixes up the normals in a random fashion, while for the simple, unmodified sphere there are no issues.

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the (array) modifier?

Comment: I think that default distance for merge by distance is too high so that it starts to merge vertexes that very close to each other

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your weld (or merge by distance) is setup correctly, just define a sharp edge and then add an auto smooth
[image]